# What does the name אהרון/Aharon mean?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, names, aharon

What does the Hebrew name אהרון, or "Aharon" translate as into English? And does that name have any meaning or significance?

Answer (score 4):

In the Yavneh Tanach (Tanach Cassuto), Shemos 4:14, Professor Elia Samuele Artom says that it is unknown.

However, at https://www.biu.ac.il/JH/Parasha/vaera/rey.html this issue is addressed at length with excellent sourcing, and suggestions of connected words include:

- הריון (conception)
- הר (mountain)
- אור (light)

among many others, see the link for full details.